# Accepting params and filtering in getter with VueX

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, nuxt.js

I've been wracking my brain on this one. I am attempting to use a getter to retrieve an object (blog post) by its "slug". However, regardless of any implementation of this getter, my state.posts.filter keeps returning "state.posts.filter" is not a function. I'm confident state has items in the array and it is defined as an array by default. So any idea why it would act this way? Based on my snippet, assume FETCH_POSTS has already been dispatched and that posts has elements in it.

I don't know if this would affect it, but I am also using this in Nuxt in the modular store format.

My Store:

```
import {createClient} from '~/plugins/contentful.js'
const client = createClient()

const state = {
   posts: []
}

// getters
const getters = {
   allPosts: state => state.posts,
   getPostBySlug: state => slug => state.posts.filter(post => post.fields.slug === slug)
}

// actions
const actions = {
   FETCH_POSTS: (state) => {
   // INIT LOADING
   client.getEntries({
     'content_type': 'article',
     order: '-sys.createdAt'
   })
  .then(posts => {
    // SUCCESS
    state.commit('SET_POSTS', posts.items)
  })
  .catch(error => {
    // FAILURE
    console.log(error)
  })
 }
}

// mutations
const mutations = {
   SET_POSTS: (state, posts) => {
      // Assign posts to state
      posts = posts.map(function (post) { post.fields.slug = post.fields.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
      return post
   })
   state.posts = Object.assign({}, posts)
  }
}

export default {
 state,
 getters,
 actions,
 mutations
}
```

And I'm calling it in my component like this:

```
export default {
    name: 'blog-post',
    computed: {
      post: function () {
        return this.$store.getters.getPostBySlug('test-slug')
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: `state.posts = Object.assign({}, posts)` this code isn't right. You're setting posts equal to a new object. Objects definitely do not have a `filter` method. Perhaps, `state.posts = posts.slice(0)`?

Comment: in addition to @Bert, `state.posts = [...posts]` would do the job as well

Comment: @Bert & Evaldo - you two are absolutely correct. not sure why I initially implemented it that way, but my eyes totally overlooked it. Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

@Bert & @Evaldo provided the correct answer. My initial assignment when dispatching my "SET_POST" mutation was to assign them the results to an empty object, instead of the appropriate array. The correct implementation would be the following.

```
// mutations
const mutations = {
   SET_POSTS: (state, posts) => {
      // Assign posts to state
      posts = posts.map(function (post) { post.fields.slug = post.fields.title.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase()
         return post
      })
      state.posts = Object.assign({}, posts)
   }
}
```